# Property value non valid at text-shadow on css

Tags: css

I'm using this css code

```
.result{
    background-color: #aaa;
    text-align: center;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 3px #000;
}
```

But the text shadow is not working the Inspector show that the value property is not valid,Do I missed something?

Comment: Don''t get confused with `box-shadow` which allows 4 values plus color.

Comment: Take a look at the doc for `text-shadow` at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow

Comment: ^ first thing to do before asking is reading the doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-shadow` shorthand only has 4 properties: X offset, Y offset, blur & Color.

```
text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #333;
```

This is different from `box-shadow` which has: X offset, Y offset, spread, blur & color.

```
box-shadow: 2px 2px 0px 4px #333;
```

(would look the same as above)

Answer (score 1):

`text-shadow` can only take 3 values ​​except color. Should be like this:

```
text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS Syntax
text-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur-radius color|none|initial|inherit;

change to text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;